# debugging hibernate annotations, can you output the hbm file?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

Is it possible to output the resulting hbm file for a class if you are trying to debug a problem?

Are there any tools that can take a hbm and convert it to annotations? or visa versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Hibernate Tools plugin](https://www.hibernate.org/255.html) for Eclipse lets you generate hbm xml and annotations